# Can't find derailleur hanger for an old Nakamura

Tags: derailleur, hanger

I tried local parts shops and tried the internet and still can't find the right hanger, And I no longer have the old broken one.

I can't even find the bike on the internet, The only photo I found was this one, Photo quality isn't the best tho.
[image]

Photos of my bike frame :
[image]
[image]

Edit: I may have found one that would fit on Marwi, I cut a few designs available on the website out of plywood using a laser machine to see if they would fit, And GH-005 seems to fit almost perfectly, I had to push into place but I think it's probably because it's wood 
[image]

Comment: Did you try this outfit:  http://wheelsmfg.com/

Comment: @DanielRHicks I just did, Unfortunately they don't seem to have Nakamura in the brands menu, I also checked 1 fastener hangers, But for some reason I can't get past page 1.

Comment: Wooden one looks great. Have you considered marketing these as an eco alternative?

Comment: Note you can file down edges on your new alu replacement if the fit is not 100% perfect

Comment: Never ever throw away an old broken hanger until the replacement is found.  Should add this to the "rules of cycling" :)

Comment: @JoeK Hmm.. I'll be considering that! And if you ever need one you know where to find me. Thank you for the Aluminum filing suggestion :)

Comment: @Criggie Definitely! Lesson learned though :)